# How to set the color of an Android ScrollView fading edge?

Tags: android, scrollview, fading

I have an Android scrollview with a white background. The fading edge is a white translucent gradient. I would like to change it be black instead of white. I have a ListView in the same project with a white background that has a black fading edge by default, but I can't find where (if anywhere) that was set.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Just found it out by trial and error.

Simply set `android:background="@color/yourColor"` for the `<ScrollView>`. It will set the shadow to the given colour.

Comment: Yep, devilishly simple. As you'd imagine, you then just have to set the scrollview immediate child to the background you want. Thanks!

Comment: Depending on the loading time of the listview this may look awkward. (e.g. listview appears with the background color before the list cells are drawn on top)...

Comment: It would be better to set the same color as background of your cells and the listview. Then just change the cachecolorhint to the desired edge fading color

Answer (score 81):

If you want a different color fading edge than the background, you have to override the ScrollView's getSolidColor() method. For example:

```
@Override
public int getSolidColor() {
    return Color.rgb(0x30, 0x30, 0x30);
}
```

Comment: I don't know why nobody has voted up what is clearly the most general and best answer. Just look at JavaDoc of View and it clearly states as much.

Comment: He's right, this is the only way to get a colored fade area while using a background image.  Just extend the ListView class.

Comment: A complete class solution for this question is posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050903/is-it-possible-to-change-the-colour-of-the-fadingedge-of-a-listview/5877824#5877824

Comment: The link Thomas Corner mentions does provide a far simpler solution if you just use a color as background for your listview.

Comment: This is the correct answer. This answer must be accepted. Awesome

Answer (score 7):

You can use:

```
    final int glowDrawableId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("overscroll_glow",
            "drawable", "android");
    final Drawable androidGlow = context.getResources().getDrawable(glowDrawableId);
    androidGlow.setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

    int edgeDrawableId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("overscroll_edge", "drawable",
            "android");
    final Drawable androidEdge = context.getResources().getDrawable(edgeDrawableId);
    androidEdge.setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Comment: Good article describing this is: http://evendanan.net/android/branding/2013/12/09/branding-edge-effect/

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT**: this does not answer the question, which was asking for `ScrollView`.  This answer only works on `AbsListView` and descendants (including `ListView`).

---

Fading edge color is controlled by the `android:cacheColorHint` attribute.

E.g.:

`<ScrollView android:cacheColorHint="#ff000000" android:background="#ffffffff" />`

will set the background to white, and the `cacheColorHint` is used to draw the fading edge color -- in this case, it would be black.

Comment: I have tried this attribute, but it does not work. It appears that this attribute/method only apply to [AbsListView](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setCacheColorHint%28int%29).

Comment: What about http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/view/View.html#setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor%28int%29 ?

Comment: I had this question about a horizontalscrollview, and the above modifications to the xml worked for it (at least on the emulator).

Comment: This works for me in the emulator (Android 2.3) but not on an actual device (Motorola Razer Android 2.3.5).

Comment: No such attribute in ScrollView!

Comment: It doesn't work for a ScrollView since that attribute doesn't exist. It works only for ListView.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this:

https://github.com/AndroidAlliance/EdgeEffectOverride

[image]

Simple clean and working perfect!

Comment: as I understand the question this is not really the solution, but I was looking for this anyways. So thanks for that

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know what changed the color of your fading edge, it was probably the application of a style or theme. Check your manifest for `android:theme="something"` in an Activity. If the theme is from the group `android.R.style.Theme.Light` the edge will be white. The default `android.R.style.Theme` and `android.R.style.Theme.Black` will have black fading edges. Themes also affect other attributes, so check out the attributes fully before you throw them in for one thing.

Comment: I have checked the Activity theme, it is @android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar  the [source of which](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/res/res/values/themes.xml&q=Theme.NoTitleBar&sa=N&cd=12&ct=rc) only contains android:windowNoTitle=true.

Comment: The comment above it:
  `<!-- Variant of the default (dark) theme with no title bar -->`

So, you are using the dark theme which includes black fading edges.
you want `Theme.Light.NoTitleBar`

Comment: I have changed to this theme, and it has not affected the fading edge color.

Comment: try setting the style on the list itself just to make sure it's not being overridden in a tighter scope

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

```
  <ScrollView
    android:theme="@style/scrollUpdate"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
```

in values\styles put the style

```
<style name="scrollUpdate">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/yourcolor</item>
    <item name="android:color">@color/yourcolor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/yourcolor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/yourcolor</item>
</style>
```

works to me tks!