# Is it possible to change the colour of the FadingEdge of a Listview?

Tags: android, listview, colors, fading

I want to give the effect that the ListView has faded from whatever is around it. By default it is set to whatever colour your ListView is. I can adjust the orientation of the FadingEdge and the size of the FadingEdge but not the colour. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can !

```
setCacheColorHint(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: Thanks, that does do what I want, but it also sets the background colour while scrolling. Is there a way to separate the two?

Comment: Give a background color to your cells.

Comment: And give your listView the same background as the cells. Obviously won't work with images as background (see solution below)

Answer (score 14):

You'll need to create a new class that extends ListView.

```
package com.mypackage;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ColorFadeListView extends ListView
{
  // fade to green by default
  private static int mFadeColor = 0xFF00FF00;
  public ColorFadeListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
  {
    this(context, attrs,0);
  }
  public ColorFadeListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
  {
    super(context,attrs,defStyle);      
    setFadingEdgeLength(30);
    setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
  }
  @Override
  public int getSolidColor()
  {
    return mFadeColor;
  }
  public void setFadeColor( int fadeColor )
  {
    mFadeColor = fadeColor;
  }
  public int getFadeColor()
  {
    return mFadeColor;
  }
}
```

You can use this list view identically to a normal `ListView` (though you'll have to cast it properly to use the fadeColor accessor methods).  In your XML, instead of defining an object as `<ListView android:properties.../>` define it as `<com.mypackage.ColorFadeListView android:properties.../>`

Comment: Is there any way to accomplish with the fading edge on the actionbar for honeycomb?

Comment: This doesn't work for me on a Motorola Razer (Android 2.3.5). I get the size 30 fade areas, but they are black. Works on a 2.3 emulator though and on a HTC Desire S with Android 2.3.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (it's a hack, I know):

```
int glowDrawableId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("overscroll_glow", "drawable", "android");
Drawable androidGlow = context.getResources().getDrawable(glowDrawableId);
androidGlow.setColorFilter(brandColor, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

I took advantage of the fact that the glow effect is actually a shared Drawable and applied a filter on it: http://evendanan.net/android/branding/2013/12/09/branding-edge-effect/