# How to change the fading orange color In ExpandableListView?

Tags: android

How can I change the fading orange color in ExpandableListView while scrolling ?

Thanks

Comment: possible dup to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050903/is-it-possible-to-change-the-colour-of-the-fadingedge-of-a-listview?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really sure what you want... I guess it is the fading color available on top and on the bottom of your list when you're scrolling.

Then set the property `cacheColorHint` to what color you want !

```
getListView().setCacheColorHint(Color.WHITE);
```

You can also disable it by doing this :

```
getListView().setFadingEdgeLength(0);
```

Comment: No this is not what I mean,

I would like to rephrase my question:

When scrolling through the various items and highlighting the group/item/row, each group/item/row are colored orange in the emulator. I would like to know how you change the highlight color (orange) to a different color?

Thanks

Comment: OK,I found what i was looking for:"setSelector(intID)"            Thanks :)