# Use selector file to get rid of orange-focus button hilite?

Tags: android, button

I took the btn_default.xml file from the android sdk under platforms/android-7/data/res/drawable-mdpi and stuck in my application's drawable directory.

Then, I took all the 9-patch images referenced in the XML file and copied those to my drawable directory also.

Next, I modified each 9-patch image having any orange in it so it was red (for testing) and saved it.

When I run my app, and focus a button with the keypad, or just touch one, I'm still getting the orange hilite color around the button.  Where is that orange hilite coming from???

This is my selector file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item 
        android:state_window_focused="false" 
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal" />

    <item 
        android:state_window_focused="false" 
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_disable" />

    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_pressed" />

    <item 
        android:state_focused="true" 
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_selected" />

    <item 
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal" />

    <item 
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_disable_focused" />

    <item
         android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_disable" />

</selector>
```

Comment: Can you try renaming the image files?  Perhaps it's still looking up the sdk (orange) versions and not your local (red) copies.

Comment: Hmm doesn't seem to matter.  Tried cleaning the project too. I think the culprit images are in this file. /android-7/data/res/drawable/btn_square_overlay.xml.  I don't think they can just be added to the selector file to be overwritten, the fields match existing ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after much digging around, I found the answer below.  It doesn't seem possible to set the selector color (btn_square_overlay_pressed.png) from a selector file.  I had to setSelector() on my gridview object which was populating it's contents from an ImageAdapter which was getting it's images from the xml selector file.

[How to change the fading orange color In ExpandableListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050981/how-to-change-the-fading-orange-color-in-expandablelistview)