# "Glooming" effect layer on the bottom of ListView

Tags: android

Currently, I have an `Activity`, with a `ListView` on the top, and `LinearLayout` on the bottom.

[image]

When a row in my `ListView` is scrolled and the row is partially shown, it looks like this. (`LinearLayout` is the one with **Value** wording)

However, I wish to have the following effect.

[image]

It seems that `LinearLayout` adds a "glooming layer" at the bottom of the `ListView`. - I am sure this is not optical illusion. :)

How I can achieve such an effect?

Comment: did you set android:fadingEdge="none" in layout for listView ?? If yes then replace none value with appropriate value, Custom fading color is not possible in android http://stackoverflow.com/a/4678136/582571

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
```

on `ListView` will solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

One of the ideas that comes in my mind right now is to [create a shape](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/24/drawing-shapes-in-android/) with a transparent gradient color. Then create a `View` above the `LinearLayout` and put the Shape as the background.

Another idea is to put a transparent image, instead of shape, above `LinearLayout`.