# Android: fade scroll bar colour and width

Tags: android

Good morning;
I have a list view in ANDROID where I want that the fadScroll bare appears event it is not cliked, after doing many research I found that I must add in XML the following line:

android:fadeScrollbars="false"

Yes it was well, it appears , but the problem I want to change its width and colour.. is it possible using simple XML code ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: This similar to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640877/how-to-set-the-color-of-an-android-scrollview-fading-edge and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678051/controlling-the-color-of-the-fading-edge-in-listviews

Comment: Just write in xml properties: `android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/darker_gray"  
 android:scrollbarSize="5dp"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible. Create a scroll bar in drawable(scrollbar.xml) using this

```
<gradient
    android:angle="45"
    android:centerColor="#669C79E7"
    android:endColor="#66C0C0C0"
    android:startColor="#669C70E2" />

<corners android:radius="8dp" />
```

and add this scroll bar like `android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar"` to your ListView

Comment: tell me please where to create it exactly ? under which file and using what type of files? thanks.

Comment: in drawable folder create a file scrollbar.xml using the given code and include that in your layout file(Listview or grid view) like android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar

Comment: I am trying please wait for me because I cant see any difference

Comment: where you create your  scrollbar.xml file

Comment: ok ok sorry because I had three layout (small , large, xlarge) I was modifying the small and testing using the large, I am sorry and thank you very much for your great answer, it was really helpufl except that i think it contains some error because I used your explanation with the followin previous code

Comment: <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" > 
    <gradient android:angle="0" android:endColor="#6699FF" android:startColor="#3333FF" /> <corners android:radius="1dp" /> 
<size android:width="1dp" /> 
</shape>

Comment: Thanks.create drawable folder in res it will be accessable to all screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListView android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_vertical_thumb" />
```

in the Drawable:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" > 
    <gradient android:angle="0" android:endColor="#6699FF" android:startColor="#3333FF" /> <corners android:radius="1dp" /> 
<size android:width="1dp" /> 
</shape>
```

Comment: Could you explain me please where is situated the DRAWABLE ?? because I have a file that is called drawable and it contains pictures..( drwable-hdpi; ldpi...ext)