# Strange White color at top and bottom of layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using a custom title bar and a LinearLayout inside a ScrollView below it. I see this strange white color while I scroll above or below. Images attached.
[image: Normal view]

Strange White color as soon as white background scrolls towards the custom title bar. Image below.
[image: Strange White color as soon as white background scrolls towards the custom title bar]

How do I get rid of this white color, it also shows at the bottom of the layout. FYI, I am using Theme.Light.

Update:
I get the same effect even at the bottom of the layout and it is more pronounced when the color in the foreground is white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the actual solution while looking into something else (serendipity!). Anyway, add this property in your view layout definition:

```
android:fadingEdge="none"
```

Comment: Yep this is perfect... :) Works!

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and it was driving me nuts. It's because the theme has a "dropshadow" by default, create a style and set it as the theme:

Style:

```
  <style name="ThemeNoDropshadow" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
  </style>
```

App manifest:

```
  <application android:theme="@style/ThemeNoDropshadow" ...>
```

Comment: Hmmm I guess I didn't get your problem then.

Comment: Somehow it does not fix it. No idea what could be wrong and this is driving me nuts too :)

Comment: Oh I see what it is now, isn't that just the scroll indicator?

Comment: Any idea how to remove the scroll indicator?

Comment: I wouldn't, given that's actually serving a purpose (in general), in action, the user should be used to seeing it.

Comment: not a super purpose; the scrollbar which pops up is a better indication of scrolling :)

Comment: Well, in newer versions, once the scrollbar disappears you can "tell" at a glance if there are more items above or below, or I guess that was their intention.

Answer (score 0):

It's the cacheColorHint, assign it transparent if you want to get rid of it, as a property of the ListView.

Annoyed me too, and I never have it.

```
android:cacheColorHint="#0000"
```

HTH

---

edit:
[How to set the color of an Android ScrollView fading edge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640877/how-to-set-the-color-of-an-android-scrollview-fading-edge)

Comment: The answer is correct for listView though what I am using is not a listview. It is a layout under scrollview and scrollview does not have this property.

Comment: see updated answer for link to another q with a similar issue