# How to change Fading Edge Color of RecyclerView?

Tags: android

I tried to solve this problem. And I got this:

1. ScrollView

   - change background color
   - change cacheColorHint color
   - change theme
2. Extends ListView and make custom ListView

```
@Override
public int getSolidColor() {
    return Color.rgb(0x30, 0x30, 0x30);
}
```

1 didn't work for me.
So, I tried to do 2. But I can't find any methods with that name in parent class which is RecyclerView.

So, In this case, It seems like RecyclerView is different from ScrollView and ListView.

How can I change the color?

Comment: Did you set both  cacheColorHint color and background color together

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the color of an Android ScrollView fading edge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640877/how-to-set-the-color-of-an-android-scrollview-fading-edge)

Comment: What did you need to change the color of what?

Comment: @RajshreeTiwari didn't work. background color change all.

Comment: @DanielBeleza It's different. And I already checked it.

Comment: @JimaleAbdi Fading Edge Color of RecyclerView.

Comment: Have you tried to create a custom style and then apply it to your ListView?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you you can try to modify this attribute:

```
<color name="colorPrimary">@color/defaultColor</color>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27343193/13431819)

The overscroll glow color inherits the primary color value set by `android:colorPrimary` in your entire app. But If you need to specify different value simply use `android:colorEdgeEffect` (only available for API 21 and above).

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="...">
   <item name="android:colorEdgeEffect">@color/my_color</item>
</style>
```